# Setting up different API URLs for dev and prod builds in Angular 2 with Webpack

Tags: angular, build, webpack

how would I go about setting up different urls for dev and prod builds with webpack? I need to be able to access the URLs in the services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By importing isDevMode and assigning the URL based on it in the app.config.

```
import { isDevMode } from '@angular/core';
this.apiEndpoint = isDevMode() ? 'dev' : 'prod';
```